# How to get grails platform-ui to read properties correctly

Tags: grails

I have this in my view

```
<ui:field bean="${orderInstance}" name="twoDayTickets" labelArgs="${[raceInstance.twoDayPrice]}" />
```

where orderInstance is an instance of

```
class Order { 
...
Integer twoDayTickets=0
... 
}
```

and I have the following property in messages.properties

```
order.twoDayTickets.label=Two Day Tickets @ £{0}
```

Given that the platform-ui docs for ui:field at http://grailsrocks.github.com/grails-platform-ui/ref/Ui%20Tags/field.html say

```
If specifying a bean, the label defaults to:

i18n message retrieved using <bean's Class>.<name>.label
...
```

I would say what I have should correctly resolve the label to the key order.twoDayTickets.label. Instead I get the default human readable interpretation of the name. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Looking [at the code](https://github.com/Grailsrocks/grails-platform-ui/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/org/grails/plugin/platform/UITagLib.groovy) it really seems that's missing the bean check, so it will always return the default human readable.

Comment: I've specified the bean property in the ui:field tag, what else do you think the documentation could mean?

Comment: I mean that the code don't do what the documentation says, you should rise an issue to this plugin.